# CompileError in Anaconda3 python 3.5 when compiling cython codes. anybody can help me out?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cython, anaconda, python-3.5

platform is window 7, using microsoft vision studio 2015. when import an cython code using import pyximport ; pyximport.install(), an error message poped out. I have no idea to solve it even I had googled a lot for this type of problems.  thanks.
the original code is someone and I am learning his code so that i can understand that. here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import cython
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
ctypedef Py_ssize_t uint

cdef inline DTYPE_t dtype_t_max(DTYPE_t a, DTYPE_t b): return a if a >= b else b

cdef inline int int_max(int a, int b): return a if a >= b else b
cdef inline int int_min(int a, int b): return a if a <= b else b


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def pool_bc01(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] imgs,
              np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] poolout,
              np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=5] switches,
              uint pool_h, uint pool_w, uint stride_y, uint stride_x):
    """ Multi-image, multi-channel pooling
    imgs has shape (n_imgs, n_channels, img_h, img_w)
    poolout has shape (n_imgs, n_channels, img_h//stride_y, img_w//stride_x)
    switches has shape (n_imgs, n_channels, img_h//stride_y, img_w//stride_x, 2)
    """
    # TODO: mean pool

    cdef uint n_imgs = imgs.shape[0]
    cdef uint n_channels = imgs.shape[1]
    cdef uint img_h = imgs.shape[2]
    cdef uint img_w = imgs.shape[3]

    cdef uint out_h = img_h // stride_y
    cdef uint out_w = img_w // stride_x

    cdef int pool_h_top = pool_h // 2 - 1 + pool_h % 2
    cdef int pool_h_bottom = pool_h // 2 + 1
    cdef int pool_w_left = pool_w // 2 - 1 + pool_w % 2
    cdef int pool_w_right = pool_w // 2 + 1

    if not n_imgs == poolout.shape[0] == switches.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError('Mismatch in number of images.')
    if not n_channels == poolout.shape[1] == switches.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError('Mismatch in number of channels.')
    if not (out_h == poolout.shape[2] == switches.shape[2] and out_w == poolout.shape[3] == switches.shape[3]):
        raise ValueError('Mismatch in image shape.')
    if not switches.shape[4] == 2:
        raise ValueError('switches should only have length 2 in the 5. dimension.')

    cdef uint i, c, y, x, y_out, x_out
    cdef int y_min, y_max, x_min, x_max
    cdef uint img_y, img_x
    cdef uint img_y_max = 0
    cdef uint img_x_max = 0
    cdef DTYPE_t value, new_value

    for i in range(n_imgs):
        for c in range(n_channels):
            for y_out in range(out_h):
                y = y_out*stride_y
                y_min = int_max(y-pool_h_top, 0)
                y_max = int_min(y+pool_h_bottom, img_h)
                for x_out in range(out_w):
                    x = x_out*stride_x
                    x_min = int_max(x-pool_w_left, 0)
                    x_max = int_min(x+pool_w_right, img_w)
                    value = -9e99
                    for img_y in range(y_min, y_max):
                        for img_x in range(x_min, x_max):
                            new_value = imgs[i, c, img_y, img_x]
                            if new_value > value:
                                value = new_value
                                img_y_max = img_y
                                img_x_max = img_x
                    poolout[i, c, y_out, x_out] = value
                    switches[i, c, y_out, x_out, 0] = img_y_max
                    switches[i, c, y_out, x_out, 1] = img_x_max


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def bprop_pool_bc01(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] poolout_grad,
                    np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=5] switches,
                    np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] imgs_grad):

    cdef uint n_imgs = poolout_grad.shape[0]
    cdef uint n_channels = poolout_grad.shape[1]
    cdef uint poolout_h = poolout_grad.shape[2]
    cdef uint poolout_w = poolout_grad.shape[3]

    cdef uint i, c, y, x, img_y, img_x

    imgs_grad[...] = 0
    for i in range(n_imgs):
        for c in range(n_channels):
            for y in range(poolout_h):
                for x in range(poolout_w):
                    img_y = switches[i, c, y, x, 0]
                    img_x = switches[i, c, y, x, 1]
                    imgs_grad[i, c, img_y, img_x] = poolout_grad[i, c, y, x]
```

then  I was importing in python 3.5

```
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from pool import pool_bc01
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 6, in 
    from pool import pool_bc01

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 445, in load_module
    language_level=self.language_level)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 232, in load_module
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module
    inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 192, in build_module
    reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
    self.build_extensions()

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)

File "C:\Users\tcao\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 386, in compile
    raise CompileError(msg)

ImportError: Building module pool failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]

Comment: It's telling you the step of compiling the C code is failing. I'm reasonably sure it will also include the error message from the C compiler and this is what you need to include to get a sensible answer. You should also include any relevant code

Answer (score 3):

The error I get is

```
fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
```

followed by a traceback similar to what you show. If [I ensure pyximport knows about the numpy include directories](https://gist.github.com/hannes-brt/757191)

```
import pyximport
import numpy as np
pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs': np.get_include()})
```

it seems to compile fine. This is with gcc rather than microsoft visual C though.

Comment: Hi DavidW, thanks. could you tell me what is gcc? probably i need to install the different compile software, rather than microsoft visual c.

Comment: It's a different compiler. But there is no reason microsoft visual C shouldn't work. The point was you might need to tell it about the include files. (Or if you're getting a different error message it'll be there, near the top)

Comment: Hi DavidW, really appreciated. I add the setup_args into the pyximport.install(). it looks the compile errors are missing. thanks.